# How to save a location breadcrumb to CoreData in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, core-location

I'm trying to save a users journey as a breadcrumb in CoreData so I can retrieve it even if they quit the app. At the moment the following code saves their location to CloudKit but I've been told in order to retrieve their breadcrumb it's best to save it to Core Data.

Just wondering how I go about that?

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     let location = locations.last!
     let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
     addCrumbPoint(center)

     // Add to Cloudkit
     let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
     locationRecord["location"] = location
     let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
     publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { 
         record, error in
     }
}
```

Comment: Will you be saving multiple breadcrumbs, or just one?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only saving one breadcrumb location, Core Data isn't appropriate. If you were saving a collection of breadcrumbs that you'd need to display, search, etc, then it might make sense.

For a single `CLLocation`, use `NSUserDefaults`. `CLLocation` conforms to `NSCoding`, so you'd convert it to an `NSData` and save:

```
let locationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(location)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(locationData, forKey: "breadcrumb")
```

When you read the data, look up the value of `"location"` and then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to convert it back to a `CLLocation`.